# Running Windows Vista Image on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-vista, images, windows-server-2003, vmware-workstation

I am planning to run a Windows Vista image on Windows Server 2003. From what I know, the VmWorstation on Windows Server 2003 doesn't support Windows Vista. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

VMWare Workstation 6.0 and above support Vista x86 and x64. What problems are you having because they shouldn't be related to Workstation's Vista compatibility.

VMWare documentation - http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/ws_pubs.html

Answer (score 0):

The host operating system dos not determine VMWare ability to run it's supported clients. If the current VMWare installation on the Server 2003 does not support Vista, all you need is to upgrade VMWare server to a more recent version.

Provided your Server 2003 machine can handle a Vista client (see page 20 of the [GuestOS Guide](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/GuestOS_guide.pdf), pdf link) all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Vmware Workstation can run pretty much anything that you can on a standard x86 or x64 based machine.

The out of the box templates that are available tell it extra features such as: if it supports virtual SCSI drives instead of IDE, what version of tools to install, USB compatibility etc.

Even if you do not see the operating system you want, the chances are, you can still run it. On the very few that won't, if you Google enough, you will find a guide that tells you how to by manually editing a VMX file.

That being said, if you cannot see Vista, just select XP - I am sure it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This afternoon I created a Windows 7 client using VMWare Workstation 6.5.3 running on a Win 2003 Server R2 box.  Workstation thinks Windows 7 is a Vista install.  It's running just fine, but no Aero.